# Does android switch to a different APN when in hotspot mode?

Tags: nexus-one, wifi-hotspot, apn

I've tried turning on the portable hot-spot mode on my nexus-one and got a message from my operator saying that my plan doesn't cover data traffic made through the `web.operator.com` APN, as opposed to `mobile.operator.com` (my "usual" APN). That made me curious. Does that mean that android switches APNs when the hot-spot feature is active? And if so, is this a built-in feature/configuration option or an operator customization?

**Update** No, the phone doesn't switch to a different APN, but I'm still not sure what triggered the message from my operator...

**Update** There's kind of a persistent rumor that European Nexus-One phones get tweaked OSes, see the xda-developers forum threads [[1]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=714747&highlight=vodafone) and [[2]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=709449&highlight=vodafone), or google nexus-one forums [[1]](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=7fd03026a89e3568&hl=en) and [[2]](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=71fe16740c60ebf0&hl=en). One of the most likely tweaks seems to be the tagging of hotspot traffic, in order to be able to charge for it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=734138 for a discussion about how they might. Mechanisms other than APN change might include

- Time to live
- Request header
- Data volume

Answer seems to be probably not.

Comment: Now that's an interesting read!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android phones indeed switch to another APN when the hotspot mode is activated. I have deleted all default APNs and replaced it with just one, hey presto, managed to transfer 128GB of personal hotspot when I only have 1GB.

Comment: How did you do that?  It won't let me delete the existing verizon APN or create a new one.